# Matlab: read multiple columns from an excel spreadsheet by using xlsread

Tags: string, matlab, xlsread

I have an Excel sheet with 300 columns, from which I just need several ranges. In a normal case I use the "import data" app. But this time it is not possible, because some of the strings are double. I just want to **read the first row and from this, several columns** (all strings).
Just as an example:
I have a first row with strings like this:

```
x= ["'[23Na]+'" ,  "'[24Mg]+'" ,  "'[25Mg]+'" ,  "'[26Mg]+'" , "'[26Mg]++'" ,  "'[27Al]+'" , "'C2H3+'" , "'[28Si]+'"]
```

And now I just want to have A1:B1 and E1:F1. How do I use here xlsread with several ranges to end with a string like this:

```
x= ["'[23Na]+'" ,  "'[24Mg]+'" , "'[26Mg]++'" ,  "'[27Al]+'"]
```

I am grateful for every hint.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are asking. Do you want to get the unique entries in the array (which is `y = unique(x)`? or are you just asking what the syntax is for indexing the values corresponding to A1:B1 and E1:F1 (which is just `y=[x(1:2) x(4:5)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope my answer will not be downvoted for trying to convince you to approach the problem differently. :-)

The problem is two-fold:

**Problem 1.** `xlsread()` doesn't support disjoint ranges. This implies that the only way to read disjoint ranges is to call `xlsread()` for each contiguous range, and then combine the results, e.g:

```
FNAME   = 'Book1.xlsx';
SHNAME  = 'Sheet1';
RANGES  = {'A1:B1', 'E1:F1'};
READFUN = @(rg) xlsread(FNAME, SHNAME, rg);

[~,~,raw] = cellfun(READFUN, RANGES, 'UniformOutput', 0);

x = [raw{:}];    % [!] depending on RANGES, this might fail
```

**Problem 2.** Every time is called, `xlsread()` **(a)** instantiates a COM server for Excel, **(b)** opens the file, **(c)** reads the data, **(d)** closes the file, and **(e)** cleans up the COM server. Steps (a), (b), (d), and (e) add A LOT OF OVERHEAD for reading just one small range at step (c).

**Approach.** I suggest to you to get **all** the raw data in one read: it will be faster and (funnily enough) less memory-intensive. You'll get a cell matrix with all the data in the sheet, but then you can process the data at your leisure, using the way-more-powerful indexing capabilities of MATLAB (compared to Excel's ranges):

```
[~,~,raw] = xlsread(FNAME, SHNAME);  % all the data, numeric or text

x = raw(1, [1,2,5,6]);

... continue processing here
```